# Running node.exe from Django on Heroku - [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

I'm deploying a Django project Heroku. I need to run `node.exe`, so I copied `node.exe` to my folder and deploy all them to Heroku.

Here is the code use with node in Django:

```
def extract_eval_unpacked(text):
    with io.open('temp.js','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text)
    cmd = 'node.exe temp.js'
    process = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=False)
    if process:
        return process.decode()
    return None
```

This works locally, but when run on Heroku I get

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node.exe temp.js': 'node.exe temp.js'
```

I checked on Heroku and I see `node.exe`:

```
$ heroku run ls
Running ls on ⬢ extractmedia... up, run.4541 (Free)
1         client_id.txt   manage.py  Procfile.windows  runtime.txt  test1.py
1.py      gettingstarted  node.exe   README.md         staticfiles
app.json  hello           Procfile   requirements.txt  temp.js
```

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to run `node.exe`, so I copied `node.exe` to my folder and deploy all them to Heroku

Don't do this.

Heroku doesn't run Windows, so it won't be able to execute a Windows binary like `node.exe`. There's a much better way to add Node.js to your application: use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

1. Set your main buildpack:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
   ```
2. Add a second buildpack for Node.js:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
   ```
3. Check your buildpacks and make sure that Python comes *last*:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks
   ```
4. Add a `package.json` file to the root of your repository, e.g. by running `npm init` or `yarn init`.

   If you depend on any specific Node.js libraries, include them as `dependencies`, e.g. via `yarn add` or `npm install --save`. Commit this file.
5. Update your Python to call `node` instead of `node.exe`. Commit that change.
6. Deploy.

You should see Node.js and any JavaScript dependencies get installed, followed by Python and all of your Python dependencies. `node` should be available at runtime.